Unity packages installed but can't be used in scripts
I am trying to use a package in my scripts but no matter what packages I try to install, it doesn't let me use any of its contents, rather even see them..
Error (active)  CS0117  'WebRTC' does not contain a definition for 'Initialize' 
Error (active)  CS0246  The type or namespace name 'VideoRenderer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 

Error (active)  CS0246  The type or namespace name 'VideoRenderer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error (active)  CS0117  'WebRTC' does not contain a definition for 'Dispose'

(https://i.sstatic.net/fzgAyEg6.png)
I already tried reinstalling (the packages and unity), playing with the packages version, clearing cache/lib, I tried much more but I can't remember
as of now, I am a bit suspicious it could be because I updated the project editor: 2022.3.42f1 -> 2022.3.43f1
(I don't remember precisely what version the project was running on but the current one is accurate)

What packages? Please provide your manifest.json.

It seems that Initialize has been removed from WebRTC package from 3.0.0-pre.6 onwards.
Here's a link dealing with this.

Same thing goes for Dispose. It was removed alongside Initialize. See Changelog

OTOH, it seems you are using Microsoft's MixedReality-WebRTC package because Untiy or Unity's own WebRTC package does not contain a VideoRenderer class, but the aforementioned MS package does. But this library does not seem to have any connection to the Unity's WebRTC, so if you have them both installed, it's meaningless.

Oh, wow.. thanks for the help, I appreciate it

The newer version of the WebRTC package updated a lot of its api and so whenever you you use a package, be sure to always check the right version's documentation.
